# Doctrine2 has problems with more than 1000 rows at select

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query which returns me all POIs in the given area:

```
    $query = $em
            ->createQuery(
                    'SELECT f FROM MyApplication\MyBundle\Entity\POI p
            WHERE (p.latitude BETWEEN :southEastLatitude AND :norhtWestLatitude) AND
                  (p.longitude BETWEEN :southEastLongitude AND :norhtWestLongitude)
            ORDER BY p.name
    ');

    $query->setParameter(":norhtWestLatitude", $northWestLat);
    $query->setParameter(":norhtWestLongitude", $northWestLng);
    $query->setParameter(":southEastLatitude", $southEastLat);
    $query->setParameter(":southEastLongitude", $southEastLng);
```

If i try to access with a small area (with params with small differences), I successfully get the result. I think I get the result up to 1000 rows... I'm not quite sure.

If i try to access with a bigger area, I get an empty resultset...

Somehow firing the same query with the params of the bigger area, I'm getting the correct resultset (~1060 rows).

So I'm wondering about limitations of doctrine (or even Symfony??? I'm using doctrine inside my Symfony2 Project), are there any? I also tried the `$query->setMaxResults(999999999);` but it didn't help...

Anybody had the same problem?

Edit: Maybe the php memory usage is to high? I added these lines before and after the getresult:

```
echo "Memory usage before: " . (memory_get_usage() / 1024) . " KB" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Memory usage after: " . (memory_get_usage() / 1024) . " KB" . PHP_EOL;
```

The output was:

> Memory usage after: 5964.0625 KB
>
> Memory usage after: 10019.421875 KB

**Edit:**
Strange tests:

1) If I test with these parameters:

```
WHERE
    (f.latitude BETWEEN 45.64273082966722 AND 47.29965978937995) AND
    (f.longitude BETWEEN 4.93262593696295 AND  9.99999999999999)
```

I'm getting 923 rows (normal behaviour)

2) If I change the parameter 9.999999999999 to 10.000000000 (or some number bigger than 9.9999999), I'm getting an empty resultset in my application.
The database still returns 923 rows (for 10.000000000).

**EDIT:**
I could fix the problem, discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/qLSon6m4nM4/y5vLztHcbDgJ

Comment: anything in app/logs/dev.log ? checked php error-log for exceeding of memory limits maybe?

Comment: Could be a memory issue and check if the related entities are also pulled or not.

Comment: Nothing interesting logged in app/logs/dev.log, and either in the php error-log nothing got logged. I don't get any error message, I'm only getting an empty resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Doctrine2 mailing list I learned that you mapped the properties as type "string":

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=false) */
private $latitude;

/** @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=false) */
private $longitude;
```

This means that your db will have VARCHAR columns for these properties. So when the db runs your query, it will perform a string-compare.

A string-compare is different from a (normal) number-compare. See these results:

```
$a = 1234567890;
$b = 987654321;

echo $a == $b ? '0' : ($a < $b ? '-1' : '1');   // output:  1 (means $a is bigger than $b)

echo strcmp( $a, $b );                          // output: -8 (means $a is smaller than $b)
```

So it's probably best to map the properties as something that represents numbers in your db (DECIMAL would be a good choice):

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", nullable=false) */
private $latitude;

/** @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", nullable=false) */
private $longitude;
```

PS: You mention you get valid results when you perform the query yourself. This is probably because you did:

```
... latitude BETWEEN 45.64273082966722 AND 47.29965978937995 ...
```

But Doctrine (because you mapped the properties as strings) will do:

```
... latitude BETWEEN '45.64273082966722' AND '47.29965978937995' ...
```

Note the quotes here. There is a big difference in how these two statements are treated, like my test-case shows ;)

Comment: absolutely correct and understandable. problem solved. thanks a lot (also for the help in the mailinglist)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to memory usage. Please check your apache log for memory errors.

When selecting large amounts of data it may be helpful to use `$query->iterate()` instead of `$query->getResult()`, [as pointed out in this article](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html).

To check if your query generates the right SQL, you could log or otherwise output the result of calling `$query->getSQL()` (after setting the parameters). Feed the resulting SQL to the database client of your choice to see if the desired result comes back.

Comment: I'm not getting a memory exhausted error, and the site you posted is mostly for bulk-changes. I'm only selecting

Comment: The second part of the article deals with selecting large quantities of items, which will decrease your memory usage. I've expanded my answer with another troubleshooting method (checking the SQL).